mapbox-gl in a React project that's being upgraded to Vite
This works fine in the CRA version of the project, but not with the upgrade to Vite. We get this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Object.Go [as transformMat4$1] (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:4733:28)
    at Ho.pointRayIntersection (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17354:15)
    at Nd.pointCoordinate (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:7829:52)
    at Ho.pointCoordinate (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17369:36)
    at Ho.pointCoordinate3D (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17372:46)
    at Ho.pointLocation3D (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17343:49)
    at Map.unproject (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:19634:35)
    at new ar (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17775:64)
    at hr.mouseout (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17832:28)
    at Xr.handleEvent (mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:18682:108)
Go @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:4733
pointRayIntersection @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17354
pointCoordinate @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:7829
pointCoordinate @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17369
pointCoordinate3D @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17372
pointLocation3D @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17343
unproject @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:19634
ar @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17775
mouseout @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:17832
handleEvent @ mapbox-gl-USTJJ6BV.js?v=d40c841a:18682
__trace__ @ @bugsnag_js.js?v=d40c841a:2238
Show 11 more frames
Show lessUnderstand this errorAI

